# Failed classifying identity: Unable to extract msp.Identity from peer Identity

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have setup the fabric network,which consist of 3org with each 2 peers total 6 peers. i am using 3 peers for chaincode for endorsing and other 3 peers for anchor peer. when i run the fabric network its working. I have created the channel transaction and anchor peer transaction using the below command

```
  export CHANNEL_ONE_NAME=mychannel
  export CHANNEL_ONE_PROFILE=Mychannel

./bin/configtxgen -profile ${CHANNEL_ONE_PROFILE} -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel- artifacts/Org1MSPanchors_${CHANNEL_ONE_NAME}.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_ONE_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
```

which create

```
Org1MSPanchors_mychannel
Org2MSPanchors_mychannel
Org3MSPanchors_mychannel
```

Inside the docker container

```
peer channel update -o orderer.avantas.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors_mychannel.tx --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```

i have the join the channel from all 3 peers, and update the anchor peer also.
when i update the anchorchannel transaction in all in 3 anchor peer, Its give me error saying

> error Authentication failed: failed classifying identity: Unable to extract msp.Identity from peer Identity
>
> WARN Identity store rejected 192.168.16.2:33260 : failed classifying identity: Unable to extract msp.Identity from peer Identity
>
> INFO streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.peer_address=192.168.16.2:33260, cannot be validated. No MSP found able to do that." grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=7.2664ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anchor peers must be part of the channel they are the anchor for, as well as the endorsing peers.

Based on your description, of your 6 peers, you are joining only 3.  It's not clear whether you are only joining the endorsing or the anchor peers, but if you do not join the anchor peers, it's possible you would observe this behavior.